# Google GCM: How many Sender class instances should I have

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

To send a PUSH notification to android device I should create a Sender class instance, than call it "send" method. After that this instance goes out of scope, and probably goes to GC.

So, Can I create one instance of Sender class (put in some singleton for example), and use it later? May be some concurrency issues present here?

Or is it better to create Sender instance on demand?

Comment: It seems like you're confused: this is exactly what a `Service` is meant to do.

Comment: What kind of service? I have GcmPushNotificator that have method sendNotification(...). In that method I create Sender instance, but in one request, code can invoke sendNotification many times, and many Sender instances will be created. Can I create one instance and use it, or no?

Comment: Just have your service spawn a thread and send the message to GCM: not hard at all.  It doesn't matter, you can create as many sender classes as you want, or no sender class.  All this requires is an `HttpRequest` object and the correct parameters.